# BA3121: Ground loop supression is great, however, very thin audio quality

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, datasheet, ground-loop

Recently I bought a couple of [BA3121](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/ROHMS30232_1-2561202.pdf)s to fight the annoying ground loop problems when using several/separated modules (MCUs, Bluetooth, USB etc.) in class-d amplifier audio projects where all the modules share the same power source.

For every solution provided, I made a test board (for isolation transformers, isolated DC/DC converters)  but there always seems to be some downside to using it (see also footnote below). Not a fan of breadboards; I like solid connections and mostly solder a demo board to try a new component.

Like this one; I followed the application example mentioned in the datasheet and it works pretty well, however, it has very thin sound. With thin sound I mean there is no bass. It sounds clear, stereo, and noise free, however  no bass. It sound like a high-pass filter was applied. I checked the connections, soldering, and wiring several times and it is exactly the same as the example.

[image: example schematic used]

[image: demo test board]

I don't think my result is the intention of the example, so what could be wrong? First thought is the small output decoupling capacitors (4.7 μF) in the example which is pretty low and by using a bigger cap in serie (for example 100 μF), on the output terminals there is more bass. However, by doing this, I change the characteristics of the circuit.

**Question:**

My question is, why does the manufacturer provide an example that produces low-quality sound or am I missing something here? Or is there an error in the schematic? Can I replace the output caps and/or input caps with a larger capacity caps without changing the ground loop characteristics? What minimal value should be used?

**Datasheet:**

When you want to take a look at the datasheet, you can find it [here](https://www.marutsu.co.jp/contents/shop/marutsu/ds/BA3121_F_N.pdf) and [here](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/rohm/ba3121.pdf).

---

*footnote (not a part of the question):*

Downsides found by using several different/other ground loop solutions:

- Isolation transformers on the output (input amplifier) is cheap and easy however can be big and bulky, reduces output capacity (volume), can reduce bandwidth especially lower frequencies;
- Isolated DC/DC converters, expensive and limited, can still introduce some whine, USB doesn't function when there is no common ground connection

---

**UPDATE 08 may 2018**

I'm very confused, the datasheet explain to increase the caps values on the Vm pins however when I do this, nothing happens, the same harsh treble-rich sound. They talk about CMMR and it doesn't affect the sound quality but the noise suppression.

However, when I changed the output caps, I tried 10 μF, 22 μF, 47 μF, 100 μF and 220 μF. When using 100 μF and 220 μF there is no difference in sound quality and it provides a rich bass, so I think 100 μF could be right.

However, there the harsh treble still exists. It is not the same as the original source, the treble is amplified.

There is even more confusion when I found the "evaluation board manual". It is practacly the same as the example in the datasheet, however, there are some resistors in series on the input path with jumper pads to be able to bypass the resistor. Especially the 50 kΩ (!) resistor, which is enabled by default. I really don't understand why you want to do this, because it kills the signal completely (or am I wrong?).

[image: Evaluation board schematic]

Because it is practically the same as the datasheet example, why do I get thin sound using the example? I don't get it. Why do I need to change the output caps and why is the sound quality not the same?

You can find the "evaluation board manual" [here](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/audio_video/ba3121f_brd_appli-e.pdf)

Comment: Bass cutoff -3dB depends on f=0.16/RC Do you know Rin?

Comment: Sorry, don't notice your comment. Rin can be different because there are different audio sources.

Comment: Then your load is non-std or too low for chip circuit design .It is not intended to drive a speaker but a power amp with a reasonably high and input impedance

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt : It doesn't drive a speaker, it acts like a pre-amplifier for a power amplifier, in this case isolated to suppress/avoid ground-loop noise on the input and finally the output of course.

Comment: If you can code you can compute RC something is wrong with your assumptions for bass response. For the tinny sound , show us a picture of your cables and system connected since this is a high game noninverting amplifier that Attenuates ground noise it’s prone to inductive feedback which will cause your results.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt : Well I made it the same like the application example and changed the 2x 4.7uF at the output, changed it now with 100uF and sounds good. The board I made is on the second picture and have an input jack and output jack. Input to the source and output to the amplifier using standard audio cable with mini-jacks.

Comment: Anyway, read allot about "common mode rejection" and it seems that most pre-amps use amplifiers (differential line receivers/Operational
Amplifiers) with PSRR/CMRR of 80db or higher.
For example found the TDA8578, TDA8579, TDA1308, NE5532, INA2134, INA134, etc. I need to buy an assembled pre-amp board/module with one these IC's, much easier and no implementation headaches.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic is not complete. There is no source of DC_bias for pin_2, pin_6.

As an aside, I'd increase the size of the caps on pin_2 or pin_5, by 5:1, so the HPF high-pass-filter behavior of the biasing drops by 2 octaves.

Perform some causal exploring.

Comment: Hai thanks for the answer. Well, this schematic is copied from the datasheet. Measuring Out:+13.6mV In: +6.4mV I already discovred that changing the caps increase sound quality however there is a reason why they provide this example. Will increasing the caps effect the isolation?

Comment: See my update at the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 4.7uF output capacitors that feed the power amplifier pass frequencies down to 20Hz when the input impedance of the power amplifier is 1.7k ohms and feeds lower frequencies when the input impedance of the power amplifier is higher.
BUT maybe these coupling capacitors have their polarity backwards? Measure the DC across them to see.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, interesting. No, the caps are mounted like the example, positives to the pins and negatives to the input/output. Measuring Out:+13.6mV In: +6.4mV

Comment: See my update at the question.